# How can I get a class variable to return a double value?

Tags: java, class, oop, constructor, object-oriented-analysis

My main class is creating a new class variable and passing in two parameters.

```
 public class Main(){

    ArrayList<Convert> newArr = new ArrayList<Convert>();

    while (moreInput()) {
        double length = getUserLength();
        double mass = getUserMass();


        Convert value = new Convert(length, mass);
      //                                               System.out.println(value);
        newArr.add(value);



public class Convert {

double mass, lenght;



    Convert(Convert values){
       length = values.length;
       mass = values.mass;

    }    Convert(double l, double m){
       mass = m;
       length = l;

    }

   public double actualconverter(Convert value) {
        double okay = (500*mass)/(length);
                                              //System.out.println(okay);
        return okay;
;
   }
```

I'm attempting to get a return value from a method in my Convert class, but it is printing the address of the index instead.  I tried debugging using print statements, so I know that the `actualConverter` method isn't getting used.

This is for an assignment, which stipulates that the main method cannot be altered in any way.

Comment: Pleade [edit] the post and format the code properly.

Comment: You already figured out that `actualConverter` is not being used, so where is the question here? Call it. And that method should not have a parameter.

Comment: This code does not compile. And you are trying to print a `Convert` object, for which you don't have overridden the `toString()` method.

Comment: I actually am trying to pass it to an array.  But yeah, I was attempting to print it to see if it was being created the way I wanted to.  My issue is getting this to work with the exact code given in the main.  I can't change it.

Comment: @okaygetithowyaliveit If u r not using convertValue method, then from which method are you expecting the return value and which variable is printing the address ? Can you clarify your question ?
The code written in main class looks fine, now what is your actual requirement ?

If the requirement in only to compile and run the code, then you need to make the varibale name as length not lenght.